# Not sure which view to use for one button scannable interface

Tags: android, gridview

I need to create an interface that supports scanning over buttons like [the Windows on-screen-keyboard does](https://youtu.be/8LZzx0wwdFc?t=1m39s). The interface should look like a Gridview. With items supplied by an Adapter.

The problem with all the views I found is that the Adapter returns items based on their position in a list, and I need them based on columns and rows to make the scanning work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you thought of recyclerview in this case as i with a RecyclerView the adapter requires the existence of a "ViewHolder" object which describes and provides access to all the views within each item row.

Comment: I never used a RecyclerView, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no adapter exists that can handle 2d arrays, you can make your own by extending BaseAdapter and implementing your own logic for mapping a regular int index to a position in your 2d array.

Comment: Depending on the screen width/height the grid would have different dimensions so I don't think this works

Comment: You could have the index be mapped to the grid such that every row of size n would be 0 to n - 1, and the next row starts at n.
So if it had 4 rows and 3 columns, and you were given a 5, it would map to the 2nd row and last column, since the first row would take 0, 1, and 2, and the next row would take 3, 4, and end at the 5

Comment: I missed the Gridview.getNumColumns() method so yes you're right